# How to migrate hibernate from 4.3 to 5.3 -Type Resolver Class

Tags: java, hibernate

I am upgrading my application from hibernate 4.3 to 5.3. I have used heuristicType method from org.hibernate.type.TypeResolver in 4.3. This class is deprecated from 5.3 version, how can rewrite this code.

Sample Code:

```java
Query query = (Query) session.createQuery(queryString);
query.setParameter(0,value,  (new TypeResolver()).heuristicType(value.getClass().getName()));
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What problem do you have?

Comment: The documentation says: _"(since 5.3) No replacement, access to and handling of Types will be much different in 6.0"_, so there is no replacement, and it looks like you will not need to do anything until Hibernate 6.

Comment: @user14900771 What type do you have for value.getClass().getName() ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're worried about it not detecting the type when the value is `null`, you can just pass a not-null constant once with `setParameter` and then the real value. The first type handler will be determined and cached for subsequent calls on the same `Query` object. Do remember, however, that 0 is an invalid index. They start at 1 in JPA. It was only due to an implementation failure that they once allowed 0-indexed parameters. Just change them to names and you'll never have to worry about it.

In short:

```
Query query = (Query) session.createQuery(queryString);
query.setParameter("name", NOT_NULL_CONSTANT);
query.setParameter("name", value); // actual value
```